# An intact area / region

Tags: word-usage, word-request, word-meaning

I was wondering what do you usually call a beautiful natural region and an area of land that is uncultivated by human and has not been used to grow crops. Such an area has no  towns, no roads have been built on it, and most of the times is protected by the government because of its beautiful scenery. Thus, it has been remained intact and undamaged by human's presence.
For instance, please have a look on the following illustrations:
[image]
[image]

Please let me know what would you use in this sense to fill in the following gap:

- If I won the lottery, I would buy a land near a/an ....... area / region in Reykjavik and build a house there.

Comment: Is there intended irony?  "I'd buy land in an area that is beautiful because there are no houses... and build a house."

Comment: It can be @JamesK. Yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wilderness** could either replace or modify *area* in your sentence.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wilderness):

> 1 a (1): a tract or region uncultivated and uninhabited by human beings
> (2): an area essentially undisturbed by human activity together with its naturally developed life community
> b: an empty or pathless area or region

See also [the Wikipedia page on "Wilderness"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilderness). The main focus of the word is the lack of human development. The connotations associated with this have changed over time, so that it could be understood as a threat or challenge in previous centuries ("taming the wilderness"), or an abstracted ideal (Disney's "Wilderness Lodge" resort).

The word is more often used as a general description than to refer to a specific area, on its own. For instance, the United States [conserves many "wilderness areas"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wilderness_areas_of_the_United_States), and many of them [use "wilderness" as part of their proper-noun name](https://www.wilderness.org/articles/article/20-popular-american-wilderness-areas). But to speak of "the wilderness" more usually speaks about the general concept than about one specific place.

Comment: Do you mean: "I would buy a house in wilderness" @Andy Bonner?

Comment: Well, your sentence does include “a,” which we’d need. I’d be inclined to say “a wilderness area.”

Comment: And the last question: "does 'wilderness' encompass both mountainous area and  forestry?

Comment: Sure, or desert, or even "marine wilderness." I added to my answer to explain *why* it's more likely to say "a wilderness area" than "a wilderness."

Comment: Thank you @Andy Bonner. Just out of curiosity, according to the definition provided by Wikipedia, perhaps governments establish protection for wilderness areas by law and thus such areas should be logically unsalable; accordingly, don't you think it would be better to say: "...I would by a land near wilderness"?

Answer (score 3):

The best word I can think of is **undeveloped**: "I would buy land in an *undeveloped* area."

As Ronald Sole suggested, "untouched" and "virgin" could possibly be used. "Virgin" is more often associated with forestry, meaning a forest that has never been logged.

Answer (score 2):

"Unspoilt" might work:

> The lush, unspoilt landscapes of Dominica offer something different from the traditional Caribbean beach wedding. (Guardian travel)

Other possibilities (from comment) untouched / virgin / pristine  However my personal preference remains with "unspoilt".

Comment: Possibly **untouched / virgin / pristine **